# I want to conditionally prefix autonumber or number filed in ms-access

Tags: ms-access-2016

*Fields*

```
[Group] (values are ARTS , PRE-MED , PRE-ENG, ICS )
```

i want data on new field called RollNo something like 18AR01"

`only 2 last digits of current year + iif([group]=ARTS,AR,iif([group]=PRE-MED,PM,iif([group]=PRE-ENG,PE,iif([group]=ICS,NULL,))))`
how this can be possible ?

Comment: Is this during original data input? via keying or via importing?  Or does the table already exist and now the new column need to be filled in?  Then also, why is the new column any different from what is available in the [Group] column?  The new column seems to replicate data that already in [Group] and redundant data is to be avoided in table design.  One or the other of these could be updated independent of the other and get out of sync.  Why not have the new column just be 2 last digits of current year.  And later concatenate the two columns when you need it?

Comment: there is a new field name RollNo where the value is calculated data type , i want something like 18AR01 means Year 18  group arts n student number 01 , i want rollnumber to be autogenerated with the conditionaly prefix of year n group

Comment: Oops, student number 01 etc...  How are we to determine this student number?  Especially after we run this once, and then add some more students, and then have to resume this numbering?   Does the number sequence all of the students, or are there four numbers sequences, one for each [Group]? (which is more complicated)!! Isn't there already a Student ID#? More duplication and redundant data?

Comment: four number sequences , one for each , can it be possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *BeforeInsert* event of the form:

```
Dim Code As String
Dim Number As Integer    

Code = Nz(Format(Date, "yy") & Switch(Me![Group] = "ARTS", "AR", Me![Group]= "PRE-MED", "PM", Me![Group] = "PRE-ENG", "PE"))
Number = Val(Nz(DMax("Right([RollNo], 2)", "YourTable", "[RollNo] Like '" & Code & "??'"))) + 1

Me!RollNo.Value = Format(Date, "yy") & Code & Format(Number, "00")
```

Comment: Thank u so much for reply,, i am begginer to ms access , can u give me brief guide where i can paste this code ?

Comment: Open the form in designview. Go to the properties pane, tab Events. Find event BeforeInsert. Select Event Procedure and click the elipsis. The code pane opens. Copy-paste the code into the procedure. Corrects control names to exactly match those of yours. Go to menu Debug and compile. Correct errors until success. Save the form.

Comment: Thank u so muchh ! i want to use primary key field as a calculated data type and i want that in as expression builder format , can you guide me how can i do this in expression builder ? because its complicated in forms

Comment: Sorry, can't tell. I never use the expression builder as I find it more confusing than helping. Besides, avoid calculated fields - use a query for calculations.

Comment: Thank u so muchhh bro :)